# How to ignore thread switches and analyze a single thread

Tags: reverse-engineering, x64dbg

I am currently using x64dbg to analyze a multi-threaded program. Every time a thread switches, x64dbg automatically breaks, which happens frequently.

I want to focus on analyzing one thread. Is there any way to disable the break on thread switches and step through only a specific thread?

As shown in the attached image, I have disabled the break events related to threads. This is the default setting.

**x64dbg option:**

[image: x64dbg option]